# Typescript cannot assign typed FormGroup

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-forms

I have a typed FormGroup and a generic component that takes a FormGroup as Input and handles the errors.

Here is what my FormGroup looks like:

```
  filterForm = new FormGroup({
    name: new FormControl<string>('', { validators: [Validators.required] }),
    authority: new FormControl<string>('')
  });
```

The error handler component declares a regular input, which evaluates as `FormGroup<any>`:

```
@Input({ required: true }) form!: FormGroup;
```

Now when I try to set `filterForm` as my error handler's `form` input I get the error:

```
Type FormGroup<{ name: FormControl<string>; authority: FormControl<string>; }> is not assignable to type FormGroup<any>.
Types of property 'controls' are incompatible. [...]
Property 'name' is incompatible with index signature.
Type FormControl<string> is not assignable to type AbstractControl<any, any>.
Types have separate declarations of a private property '_parent'.
```

While I understand the error, I don't know how to solve this and how to type my `@Input` so that I can use any typed FormGroup as a parameter. What I really use is the form's global invalid status and the indexable `controls` object to go over individual field errors, so I don't care about the form's type within my component.

Comment: It doesn't make sense that it doesn't work; `FormControl<string>` _is_ assignable to `AbstractControl<any, any>`.
It works for me in this stackblitz: https://stackblitz-starters-hs2kgr.stackblitz.io.
Could you try updating your dependencies? Or comparing your config with the stackblitz?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you have going on, but this can happen when there is more than one version/copy of @angular in your workspace.

In my case, I am developing and referencing my own library project (my-lib) in an application (my-app) and my library is using its own @angular packages and the app is using its own @angular packages.

Because they live in two different locations, even though they can be exactly the same version, the compiler views them as different libraries.

The solution is to tell your app to ONLY use one version/copy of @angular by redirecting ALL @angular references to a single spot by adding the entry below in your tsconfig.json file of your application.

```
"compilerOptions": {
  "paths": {
    "@angular/*": [
      "./node_modules/@angular/*"
     ]
  }
}
```

I'm not sure if this is what you have going on, but thought I'd share in case it helps you out.

Comment: I won't be able to try your solution as my component no longer exists, but I believe this is what was going on. I am also working with my own lib and didn't think this info actually mattered since both Angular versions were exactly the same. I'll keep your answer in mind next time I have some typing magic going on with a lib!